# Getting Can't set header after they are sent error when i render data with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I am getting "Can't set header..." Error when i try to include my header file and render data from express.

This is my code

```
   router.use('/dreams', function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.url.split("/").pop()){
            var checkreq = {
                "request" : "singledream",
                "dreamId" : req.url.split("/").pop()
            }

            var getdreams = require('./getdreams.js');

            getdreams(checkreq, function(dreamd){

                  res.render("dreamdetail");

            });

    }

    else{
        //res.render("notfound");
        res.send("notfound");
    }
});
```

This is my getdreams code:-

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 



var PostSave = require('./myschema.js').PostSave;

// UserReg for getting user detail like Profile Image.
var UserReg = require('./myschema.js').UserReg;

var GetUserDetails = function(userId, mycallback){
  var  aa;

                UserReg.findOne( { UserId: { $eq: userId } } ).exec(function(err, post) {
                    mycallback(post)
                });

};

module.exports = function(checkreq, callback){
    var bb;             

    if(checkreq.request === "forallposts"){

        // front page request on refersh
        var dreamdata = PostSave.find({}).sort({'post_reg_time': -1}).limit(20);


    }

    else if(checkreq.request === "singledream"){

        // front page request on refersh
        var dreamdata = PostSave.find({PostId: { $eq: checkreq.dreamId }});


    }

    else{
                // pagination 

                var dreamdata = PostSave.find( { PostId: { $lt: checkreq } } ).sort({'post_reg_time': -1}).limit(20);

    }
            dreamdata.exec(function(err, posts) {
                 // `posts` will be of length 20
                 if(err){
                     callback(err);
                 }
                 //console.log(JSON.parse(posts));
                 callback(posts);
            });




 };
```

Now if i render data in dreamdetail file i get this error. If i use res.send(dreamd) then i got data. Don't know why getting error with render.Tried a lot. Got some good ranking answers but couldn't fix my issues. Please help me fixing this Error.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably also show your code for `getdreams`.

Comment: added my getdreams file code. thanks

Comment: You should add a `return;` after `callback(err)` in your `getdreams()` implementation so as not to call `calblack()` more than once.

Comment: Yes. its Working Now.Thank You. :)